# External Entities in DTD with SYSTEM are not resolved in PHP

Tags: php, xml, external, dtd, entities

I can't figure out the following issue. I want to resolve an external entity in a DTD based on SYSTEM: 
I run on the latest Ubuntu 12.10.. no custom changes!

I have the following PHP test code:

```
<h1>simpleXml Demo</h1>
<form name="input" action="" method="POST">
  <textarea  name="xmlInput"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['xmlInput']) and strlen($_POST['xmlInput'])>0){
    $doc = simplexml_load_string($_POST['xmlInput']);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($doc);
    echo "</pre>";       
?>
```

**Example 1:** 
When running this XML file, the entity &foo; is resolved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE results [
  <!ENTITY test "some text,">
]>
<results>
  <result>This result is &test;</result>
</results>
```

**Example 2:** 
When running this XML file, the entity &foo; is just replaced by nothing - no errors at all!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE result [
  <!ENTITY test SYSTEM "http://textfiles.com/food/btaco.txt">
]>
<results>
  <result>This result is &test;</result>
</results>
```

I already played with 'libxml_disable_entity_loader()', it didn't change anything!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the LIBXML_NOENT option at the time you parse the XML data.  It is counter-intuitive, but this will enable external entities and the request to the URL will occur.

Comment: Can confirm that this worked with my setup. I was experiencing the same exact problem as OP. Thanks for the idea!